# What does Return do?

Tags: javascript, string, return

What does the code

```
return
```

do in a coding problem like:

```
    var creditCheck = function (income) {
   if (income>=100){
        return ("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.");
}
    else {
        return ("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.");
}
};

creditCheck(75);
creditCheck(125);
creditCheck(100);
```

I'm not really seeing why CodeAcademy had me do this because it'd be more preferable to see console.log options for each of the 3 creditCheck things there, which can also be done by replacing return with console.log obviously. :\ So what does return do and do I ever really need to use it in the first place?

I have understanding of the code I am writing, I was concerned about the return function because I was under the impression it also printed something in the console. Please unflag this so other people can look this information up. Thank you.

Comment: See here: http://www.quora.com/JavaScript/What-does-the-return-keyword-do-in-JavaScript

Comment: It returns (with the option) a value to the code that called it.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return): "*Specifies the value to be returned by a function.*"

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you call a function and it gives you a value. The value that it gives is called the *return value*, and `return` is the keyword that is used in a return statement, i.e. the statement that causes the function to finish execution and return a value.

Nothing interesting happens here because you're calling the `creditCheck` function without doing anything with the return value. What happens instead is that the return value is silently discarded.

You can, of course, run that code in your developer console, but you'll need to call `console.log` like so:

```
console.log(creditCheck(75));
console.log(creditCheck(125));
console.log(creditCheck(100));
```

Here the return value of each call to `creditCheck` is passed directly as an argument to `console.log`, much like how you're passing a number to `creditCheck`.

Alternatively, you can assign the return value to a variable, and pass that variable to `console.log` instead, like so:

```
var result = creditCheck(75);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns a value from the function. Basically, you can do some calculations and check some conditions depending on the function parameters (`income`), and return some result. You can use functions later:

```
var phrase = creditCheck(125); // phrase is equal to "You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."
alert(phrase);
```